# Access Amazon Couchbase Instance from local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchbase

Having problems to access instance of Couchbase running on Windows machine in EC2 Amazon Cloud. I can access it in RDP, but not from my local browser. Checked a security group have all traffic opened.

What could be a problem?

Trying to access it gives me an error: This webpage is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Forgot to open 8091 port in Windows Firewall